# how to dynamically group in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, expression

I want to create a jasper report where it should be able to group from given field name. Simply the grouping option should be done dynamically. And this is not the SQL grouping, but the report grouping of similar elements.

Is there any way where I can do achieve this task. I guess the solution is to select a dynamic field for given parameter and create a group in the report by giving this dynamically selected field. I tried the following thing, but no luck. If I can use the below expression as the group expression I think I may succeed.

```html
$F{$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getParameterValue( $P{GROUP_BY_PARAM} )}
```

But this statement fails as there is no such value assigned for the parameter $P{GROUP_BY_PARAM}. since then this is not compiled by the compiler saying no such field defined.. Have I missed something or is there any other solution available ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the best way, but this will work.

```
<group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[($P{GROUP_BY_PARAM}==1)?$F{PARAM1}:$F{PARAM2}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="37">
```

Obviously if you had a lot of parameters, then this could be a bit messy (you would have to have nested conditional statements) and you would have to actually write out the names of the parameters PARAM1 and PARAM2...

See [JasperReports grouping changeable by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587511/jasperreports-grouping-changeable-by-user?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
See also [Grouping by parameter value in jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369285/grouping-by-parameter-value-in-jasper)